# how to remove overflow and add bootstrap to only one component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on a webpage.A first i have just build my webpage in normal html and css. so there are 2 pages and i have to give routing for it. as i cant  do routing in normal html and css i have copied it to an Angular project to set routing and other functionalities. i made 2 components for 2 pages and copied all the html and css code to it. but after copying the overflow cant be hidden even  though i have given `overflow:hidden` in the css of the page.cant do anything with it. Any solutions?

another one problem faced is that only one of my page requires bootstrap. but i cant put bootstrap to any one component. Any solution for this?

Comment: can you elaborate what file structure for CSS you are using in the project

Comment: Can you please add minimum reproducible example?